# Buscar seguidores de una cuenta de twitter usando python

Tags: python, tweepy

Hola estoy intentando buscar los seguidores de una cuenta de `twitter` usando `python`.
Lo que hice fue esto, pero me busca los usuarios que yo sigo. Y solo me imprime uno. Necesito que me imprima todos los **SEGUIDORES** de la cuenta.
Alguno me da una mano?

```
import tweepy

consumer_key='WjH7YmuRQP0Aq0u20YWQqXIpG'
consumer_secret='yg7oaMjGPwyu47ilP8GVhTkWxm3NJPhYJnRnIbxKqkHRNorE81'
access_token='922967657988673536-aT8byXalXV86aBiLs7ATW5CZGAjAboX'
access_token_secret='KeyYPINllDbT5sVtlfvA1Z2liyS34PbcFm5c1FrNxAkTm'
auth=tweepy.OAuthHandler(consumer_key,consumer_secret)
auth.set_access_token(access_token,access_token_secret)
api= tweepy.API(auth)

def seguidores(api):

    try:
        usuario=str(input("ingrese su nombre de usuario colocando el arroba @: "))
        if usuario[0]=="@": 
            user=api.get_user(usuario)
            for friend in user.friends() :
                print(friend.screen_name.encode('utf-8'))
                return()
        else:
            usuario="@"+usuario
            user=api.get_user(usuario)

            for friend in user.friends():
                print(friend.screen_name.encode('utf-8'))
                return()
    except tweepy.TweepError as err:
        print("Error: ", err)
        return -1
seguidores(api)
```

Comment: Quita los `return` de los ciclos `for`, esto hace que tu función/método retorne en la primera iteración del ciclo.

Comment: Claro, ahi me imprimio mas usuarios. Pero me esta imprimiendo los usuarios que la cuenta sigue. Yo necesito que me imprima los seguidores de la cuenta.

Comment: Te funciono mi respuesta?

Answer (score 2):

Para obtener los seguidores lo debes hacer a traves del método `followers()`:

```
def seguidores(api):
    try:
        usuario=str(input("ingrese su nombre de usuario colocando el arroba @: "))
        if usuario[0] != "@": 
            usuario="@"+usuario
        user=api.get_user(usuario)
        for follower in user.followers():
            print(follower.screen_name.encode('utf-8'))
    except tweepy.TweepError as err:
        print("Error: ", err)
        return -1
seguidores(api)
```